# Sending a "google.visualization.Table" via Email

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-visualization

I have a PHP script - in which I'm creating google.visualization.Table object in javascript.
I want to send the table created via Email - but for now the email is sent as empty...

EDIT:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
            google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
            var data;
            function drawTable() {
            data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            $datacols
            data.addRows($alldata);
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
            var formatter = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
            formatter.addRange(null, 0, 'red', null);
            $formatcols
            allowHtml=true;

            var cssClassNames = {    'tableCell': 'mycell-td', 'headerCell': 'myhead-td gradient'};

            table.draw(data, {allowHtml: true, width: '100%',showRowNumber: false, 'cssClassNames': cssClassNames});
            document.getElementById('Download_CSV').style.visibility = \"visible\"; //Enable download CSV button when data is available
    </script>
```

The script above is concatenated to a string with additional code, and then sent by email.
Does anyone know how can I do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Post the code you've tried  and it's possible that someone can help.

Comment: @InbetweenWeekends I've attached the script code - if you can help :)

Comment: you could possibly [send the chart as an image](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing)